# How to add passed parameter timezone and get hh:mm A zz format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to add the time zone in the below code ,

```
const Timeformat = moment("2020-06-03T07:48:59Z", 'h:mm:ss A', "Asia/kolkata")
.utc()
.format('h:mm A zz')
```

do i need to change any format here??

but always i get  output as

```
"3:18 AM Coordinated Universal Time"
```

Expected output is

```
"3:18 AM IST"
```

Comment: You've changed it to UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) using `.utc()`. If you don't want it in UTC, don't call `.utc()`. I strongly suggest taking some time with [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/) before asking questions here. A lot of your recent questions are ones easily solved by reading it and trying things out.

Answer (score 0):

without a moment library, you can do as

```js
    let now = new Date('2020-06-03T07:48:59Z')

    let result = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
      hour12: true,
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric'
    }).format(now)
    
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment , But i am using Moment js throught out app and this doesnt add  IST to end of the time